# JPA com "detached entity passed to persist:"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência

Olá, estou com um problema pois uso uma tabela intermediária para salvar os IDs de outras 2 tabelas. Só que da maneira que mapeei, não consigo salvar nessa tabela pois aparentemente o JPA entende que não posso passar a entidade nula e nem passar o objeto preenchido para q ele faça um "MERGE" sem alteração, segue:

```
instance.setDtCriacao(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
instance.setQtMidiaTransmissao(dualListMidias.getTarget().size());
instance = playlistBean.salvarPlaylist(referenceValue);

int i = 1;
for(Midia midias : dualListMidias.getTarget()){             
    MidiaPlaylist midiaPlaylist = new MidiaPlaylist();
    MidiaPlaylistPK midiaPlaylistPK = new MidiaPlaylistPK();
    midiaPlaylistPK.setIdMidia(midias.getIdMidia());
    midiaPlaylistPK.setIdPlaylist(instance.getIdPlaylist());                
    midiaPlaylist.setPk(midiaPlaylistPK);               
    midiaPlaylist.setNrOrdem(i++);
    midiaPlaylist.setMidia(midias); 
    midiaPlaylist.setPlaylist(instance);

    //playlistBean.salvar(midiaPlaylist);
    midiaPlaylistBean.salvar(midiaPlaylist);
}
```

Salvo na tabela "playlist" para que tenha o ID que quero e os IDs de mídia já estão na lista `dualListMidias.getTarget()`, logo faço um for para gravar todos os id.playlist e id.midia na tabela midiaPlaylist

Meu MidiaPlaylistBean

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public MidiaPlaylist salvar(MidiaPlaylist entity){
    try{
        entity = super.save(entity);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Meu MidiaPlaylist

```
@EmbeddedId 
private MidiaPlaylistPK pk = new MidiaPlaylistPK();

public MidiaPlaylist(){
}

@MapsId("idMidia")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_midia", referencedColumnName="id_midia")
private Midia midia;

@MapsId("idPlaylist")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_playlist", referencedColumnName="id_playlist")
private Playlist playlist;  

@Column(name="nr_ordem", nullable=false)
private int nrOrdem;


public Midia getMidia() {
    return midia;
}

public void setMidia(Midia midia) {
    this.midia = midia;
}

public Playlist getPlaylist() {
    return playlist;
}

public void setPlaylist(Playlist playlist) {
    this.playlist = playlist;
}

public void setPk(MidiaPlaylistPK id) {
    this.pk = id;
}

public MidiaPlaylistPK getPk() {
    return this.pk;
}

public void setNrOrdem(int nrOrdem){
    this.nrOrdem = nrOrdem;
}

public int getNrOrdem(){
    return this.nrOrdem;
}
```

Playlist.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_playlist")
private Long idPlaylist;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "playlist", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<MidiaPlaylist> midiaPlaylist;

public List<MidiaPlaylist> getMidiaPlaylist(){
    return midiaPlaylist;
}

public void setMidiaPlaylist(List<MidiaPlaylist> midiaPlaylist){
    this.midiaPlaylist = midiaPlaylist;
}

public Playlist() {
}   

public Long getIdPlaylist() {
    return this.idPlaylist;
}

public void setIdPlaylist(Long idPlaylist) {
    this.idPlaylist = idPlaylist;
}
```

**O erro é**:

> detached entity passed to persist: com.bcm.midia.database.entity.Midia

**Onde eu acho q está o erro**: no mapeamento de Midia

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_midia")
private Long idMidia; 

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "midia", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)   
private List<MidiaPlaylist> midiaPlaylist;
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o porque eu não consigo apenas salvar na tabela MidiaPlaylist desta forma de mapeamento many-to-many?

Comment: `entity = super.save(entity);` - O que faz esse método `save`?

Comment: Método que extend de um abstrato (extends BussinessAbstract<MidiaPlaylist>) para persistir, basicamente um getDAO().save(entity).

Comment: Onde está o método setIdPlaylist? Não colocasse o código...

Comment: Adicionei agora na edição. A classe MidiaPlaylistPK armazena os long dos ids de playlist e midia

Comment: Você faz esse set: midiaPlaylistPK.setIdPlaylist(instance.getIdPlaylist()). Onde está o método?

Comment: Adicionai a classe. No caso é uma relação many to many entre playlist e midia onde é salvo os IDs e ordem na tabela MidiaPlaylist. Consigo consultar tranquilo com esse mapeamento. o problema é gravar